# Visual Basic sent data to api as json object

Tags: vba, api

Good day i am try to sent data to api as json object like that

```
   "Content-Type: application/json" 
  "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" 
 -d '[ 
       { 
           "datetime": "2021-02-21 14:07:37", 
           "isRefund": false, 
           "receiptNumber": "880090", 
           "amount": 164.22 
       } 
   ]'
```

and this my code :

```
Sub X2()
'  Dim xhr As Object
  
Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  xhr.Open "POST", "https://tenanttest.api.rubixpark.com/api/v1/sales", False

  xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  xhr.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken

  xhr.setRequestHeader "datetime", Now()
  xhr.setRequestHeader "isRefund", False
  xhr.setRequestHeader "receiptNumber", 111
  xhr.setRequestHeader "amount", Format(1000#, "##,##0.00")
  xhr.send
  
  If xhr.Status = 200 Then
   MsgBox xhr.ResponseText

  Else
  End If


End Sub
```

so i would like to sent access token only on header and other data on body as json object like first block of code any help and thanks

Comment: Note, your first example actually sends an _array_ with one object inside of it, not the object directly.

Comment: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON is typically recommended for working with JSON in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Would look like this:

```vb
Dim xhr As Object

Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xhr.Open "POST", "https://tenanttest.api.rubixpark.com/api/v1/sales", False

xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xhr.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken
xhr.send "[{""datetime"": ""2021-02-21 14:07:37"",""isRefund"": false," & _
         """receiptNumber"": ""880090"",""amount"": 164.22}]"

If xhr.Status = 200 Then
    MsgBox xhr.ResponseText
End If
```

Comment: I have a problem in datetime when I add value of datetime thanks for help

Comment: You can use `Format()` to get the string you need to insert there.  Eg: `Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")`