# Visual Basic sent date time on json object format

Tags: vba, api

I am asking if there is anyone can help me on visual basic , i am try to sent date time to my api as json object when i sent date time static recording without issue my problem when i am sent dynamic date time this is my function and json that needed from api and accepted

```
Dim xhr As Object

Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xhr.Open "POST", "https://tenanttest.api.rubixpark.com/api/v1/sales", False

xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xhr.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken
xhr.send "[{""datetime"": ""2021-02-21 14:07:37"",""isRefund"": false," & _
         """receiptNumber"": ""880090"",""amount"": 164.22}]"

If xhr.Status = 200 Then
    MsgBox xhr.ResponseText
End If
```

How can change this static date time with dynamic current date time and sent on json object as recored to api

Thanks

Comment: Already asked and answered in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245279/visual-basic-sent-data-to-api-as-json-object/68248679#comment120698472_68248679

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```vb
Const SendText ="[{""datetime"": ""{0}"",""isRefund"": false," & _
         """receiptNumber"": ""880090"",""amount"": 164.22}]"

Dim SendJson As String
Dim SendDate As Date

SendDate = Date

SendJson = Replace(SendText, "{0}", Format(SendDate, "yyyy-mm-dd hh\:nn\:ss")
xhr.send SendJson
```